# Nested Ask referencing different breeds in Netlogo

Tags: nested, netlogo

I'm trying to get one type of breed to evaluate all the agents in another breed, and choose which one it likes best based on its own preferences of the characteristics of the other breed.

lets say i have two breeds, men and women. the women have random values for characteristics (variables generated at birth), lets say some value 0 to 10 for intelligence and attractiveness. The men have preferences (also variables generated at birth) about how much they care about those characteristics. I'd like the men to choose which woman they prefer most using a utility function, and move to them.

my code looks something like this:

men own [ pref-int pref-att ]
women own [ int att utility ]

```
to choose-mate
 ask men [
  let pref-int [pref-int] of myself
  let pref-att [pref-att] of myself
  ask women [
     let int [int] of myself
     let att [att] of myself
     set utiilty pref-int*int + pref-att*att
     ]
  move to max-one-of women [ utilty ] 
 ]
end
```

but netlogo doesn't seem to be able to access the variable values of women one I've referenced men with ask.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple problems:

1. One problem is that your local variables `pref-int` and `pref-att` have the same name has the men-own variables. Variables need unique names in general.
2. `myself` refers to the agent that is calling the current agent (it's probably the most confusingly named primitive in NetLogo). `self` refers to the current agent. It looks like you're using `myself` where you should be using `self`. However, `[ some-variable ] of self` is the same as `some-variable`, so you rarely use `self`. NetLogo automatically figures out who's variable you're referring to from the context.
3. You need spaces around the `*`s.
4. `move to` should be `move-to`.

So here are two ways to do what you're trying to do.

Using local variables:

```
to choose-mate
 ask men [
  let mans-pref-int pref-int
  let mans-pref-att pref-att
  ask women [
     set utiilty mans-pref-int * int + mans-pref-att * att
     ]
  move-to max-one-of women [ utilty ] 
 ]
end
```

Using `myself`:

```
to choose-mate
 ask men [
  ask women [
     set utiilty ([pref-int] of myself) * int + ([pref-att] of myself) * att
     ]
  move-to max-one-of women [ utilty ] 
 ]
end
```

I prefer the `myself` version, but it's a matter of taste.

Also, another observation. `utility` is changing with every man. Its not a global attribute of a particular woman, but rather something specific to each man. As such, I wouldn't recommend storing it as a woman-own variable. Instead you can do:

```
to choose-mate
 ask men [
  move-to max-one-of women [ 
    ([pref-int] of myself) * int + ([pref-att] of myself) * att
  ] 
 ]
end
```